# Full list of option key mappings in Mac keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keybindings

The option key with any alphanumeric or symbol key in a Mac keyboard would insert a special character. The special character would also change when shift is also held with option.

E.g., the following are what I use everyday.

- Option + hyphen = en dash
- Option + Shift + hyphen = em dash
- Option + E = acute accent

Apart from that, I could not find a comprehensive mapping document for each key without a trial and error.

Can anyone share such a document or link?

ANSI US Keyboard, macOS Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: Some helpful pages:  https://slcr.wsu.edu/help-pages/keyboards-osx/ and https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-type-common-symbols-and-special-characters-in-os-x/

Comment: Thanks a lot @IconDaemon, though not all of them seem to apply (p becomes π in my keyboard), it is certainly helpful.

Comment: Are you basically asking to open the Keyboard Viewer, snapshot the combinations, then print them… or just leave it open until you learn them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily see how all the keys are mapped with Apple's [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/12.0/mac/12.0).